# parsing a string using a Lucene Analyser

Tags: lucene.net

How can you use an Analyser to 'analyse' a string, and return the analysed string?

I am trying the below code found off this site, but it is throwing an `ArgumentException` - "This AttributeSource does not have the attribute Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute"

```
     public static string AnalyseString(Analyzer analyser, string stringToAnalyse)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        sw.Write(stringToAnalyse);
        sw.Flush();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);

        TokenStream tokenStreamResult = analyser.TokenStream(null,sr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Lucene.Net.Analysis.Token t = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Token();

        while (tokenStreamResult.IncrementToken())
        {
            var attrib = tokenStreamResult.GetAttribute<TermAttribute>();

            string t2 = tokenStreamResult.GetAttribute<TermAttribute>().Term;

            sb.Append(t2 + " ");


        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I am using the latest Lucene.Net version (3.0.3.0), and am testing with a `SimpleAnalyzer`

Answer (score 3):

Try tokenStreamResult.GetAttribute<**ITermAttribute**>() instead